# ASPxGridView - The width of columns are not equal if ColumnResizeMode is set to Control or NextColumn

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I added ASPxGridView  with Customization window to hide/show columns , and two buttons to save and load client layout , i hide a column and save layout to session variable  , after that i reload the layout from session and restore the hidden column but its width is set to zero.

is There any idea?

Comment: Any code. Not very clear what exactly your question is. What do you mean by "previous column's width is set to zero" ?

Comment: i mean that , drop (birthdate) column for example from list to grid , the (birthdate) column add to left by the end use need to resize it manual.

Comment: you may enable this by using SettingsCookies properties of aspxgridview ,this properties save current state into Cookies.